# Meaning of なにもやってないだけじゃない

Tags: grammar, particle-だけ

I'm not really sure about the meaning of this sentence. I think it means "I can't stand without doing something" but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what you don't understand? Is there a specific word/section or grammar point that is making you confused?

Comment: Is this from the song 「何やってもうまくいかない」? This context would have been immensely helpful to include in your post to begin with